# Mongoose - aggreate to aggregated object?

Tags: mongoose

Now i am using query like this:

```
const results = await User.aggregate([{$match: {"email": 'email here'}},{ $lookup:{ from: "businesses", localField: "businessId", foreignField: "_id", as: "businesses" } }]);
```

and i need to get other objects that belong to every single business, what is the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...

```
const qwery = await User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "email": 'email here' }
  },
  {  
    $lookup: { from: "businesses", localField: "businessId", foreignField: "_id", as: "business" }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "superpages", localField: "_id", foreignField: "userId", as: "superpages",
      pipeline: [{ $lookup: { from: "subpages", localField: "_id", foreignField: "superPageId", as: "subpages" } }] ----------> THIS IS WHAT I NEEDED
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$business'
  }
]);
```

All i needed is this:

```
pipeline: [{ $lookup: { from: "subpages", localField: "_id", foreignField: "superPageId", as: "subpages" } }]
```